# Find top 2 values in an object not working - Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I am trying to find top 2 values in an object that is in an array, but it is not working. I already to this, but for some average values that are not in an array and it works, but when I loop through some results, and try to find top 2 values for each of the results, it shows an error...

This is how my code looks like:

```
// Models:

export class Results {
    public capture_at: string;
    public comment: string;
    public emotion_average: EmotionAverage;
    public location: string;
    public os_type: string;
    public sdk_value: string;
    public user: string;
    public uuid: string;
    public topTwo: TopTwo;
}

export class TopTwo {
    public label: string;
    public value: number;
}

export class EmotionAverage {
    public anger: number;
    public contempt: number;
    public disgust: number;
    public engagement: number;
    public fear: number;
    public joy: number;
    public sadness: number;
    public surprise: number;
    public valence: number;
}
```

Code when I get the data inside the component:

```
for (const emotion of this.activeCampaignModel.video.emotion.results) {
    emotion.topTwo = Object
    .entries(emotion.emotion_average)
    .sort(({ 1: a }, { 1: b }) => b - a)
    .slice(0, 2)
    .map(([label, value]) => ({ label, value }));
}
```

The error im getting is :

> Type '{ label: string; value: any; }[]' is not assignable to type
>   'TopTwo'.   Property 'label' is missing in type '{ label: string;
>   value: any; }[]'.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you create a plunker or a stackblitz for this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing your map

```
.map(([label, value]) => ({ label, value }));
```

To this?

```
.map((label, value) => ({ label, value }));
```